# Using vertical-align property to align div to top AND bottom of siblings (keep divs same height)

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS code and a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nicholaschris/RguYV/)

I would like to know whether or not I can use the `vertical-align` CSS property to keep the div which has more text in alignment with the other divs when the browser window is resized. Currently when the browser window is resized the div with more text extends down or up depending on whether `vertical-align` is set to `top` or `bottom`.

In other words the height of the div with more text increases and the others do not. How can I keep the heights of the yellow divs equal without setting height property?

```
<div class="red-box">
  <div class="yellow-box">
    <img src="">
     <h1>heading one</h1>

    <p>Little text one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="yellow-box">
    <img src="">
     <h1>heading two</h1>

    <p>Little text two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="yellow-box">
    <img src="">

     <h1>heading three</h1>

    <p>Lots of text that
        just keeps on going and going</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.red-box {
  background:red;
}

.yellow-box {
  background: yellow;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  /* vertical-align: top; */
}
```

Comment: the vertical-align property is not reliable, at least for me. I don't see anyway your going to be able to do this without setting a height property because your wanting to target height

Comment: The `vertical-align` property usually only works well with `display:table-cell;` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the display property of .yellow-box to...

```
display: table-cell;
```

Comment: This certainly fixes the problem in the JSFiddle example, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tables are long deprecated for layout purposes, but they are still good for tabular data. Your example seems to be some kind of tabular data, so you could consider using a table. Otherwise you will have to use heights: `100% height` for the yellow boxes should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align` property works with `table-cell` and `inline level` elements. `inline level` means `inline`, `inline-block` and `inline-table`.

As you have `display: inline-block` on the `div`s (default being `block`), you can use `vertical align`.

But I am not sure what you want to achieve.

[**`+ w3 | vertical-align`**](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align)